# Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode (Google play services)

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm getting the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
```

When I'm pressing `Enable Google Play Services` in my app.

The code I have is

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    Log.d("resultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("FUApp", "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here's the StackTrace of the error

```
01-29 14:15:30.714  10725-10725/com.example.fitnessunlimited.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.fitnessunlimited.android, PID: 10725
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:837)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.i.onClick(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this error? Pressing the enable button works on Google Now, just not in the app I'm building.

Comment: Where are you starting this activity? Paste that code.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375239/acra-exception-can-only-use-lower-16-bits-for-requestcode

Comment: @ZohraKhan It's the default Activity, it's launched when the app is

Comment: I can see only half comment. I mean when you are pressing button you might be sending intent to start this. Please post that code.

Comment: I don't write any code for the button press, it's all handled by the above code.

Comment: When I'm pressing Enable Google Play Services in my app. You have written this line in question.

Comment: No, this is pre-written by Google

Comment: Gimme your full code.

Comment: See my answer, I found the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, GooglePlayServicesUtil.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE)
```

Changing that line to

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 9000)
```

made the button work correctly and open up the settings page.

Comment: K good votes up. Define that literal in this way private final static int
            CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000; because CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST can be used at some other location.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got the number from, I've moved it into that variable now I've seen it works

Comment: Sorry, It was easy to crack but I never read the full line of getErrorDialog. Just by seeing logcat I always assume its something with startAcitivityResult.

Comment: Why 9000 and not 10 or 1. What is the difference here? I have seen different numbers out there.

Comment: 9000 is entirely arbitrary. It just needs to be something you're not already using elsewhere as an activity request code (as in onActivityResult's requestCode) and needs to be below 65536 for arcane Android reasons.